# Tracking who a googledoc was shared with

Tags: google-drive-sharing, tracking

Yesterday I was editing a share list on an excel document.  I deleted an email, thinking that it was an out-of-date contact.  Now I learn that the owner of that email should never have been there.  This is a hack by a known individual.  Is there a way to recover the fact that the email was part of the share?

Answer (score 0):

You can see who you shared it with and who was removed in Activity.[image]